# How to fix "cannot find derive macro `FromRow` in this scope"?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket, rust-sqlx

I try to create a connection with a PostgreSQL databse using the Rocket framework.

This is my cargo.tml:

```
[package]
name = "TestRust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.3"
rocket = { version = "=0.5.0-rc.3", features = ["secrets"] }
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }

[dependencies.rocket_dyn_templates]
version = "=0.1.0-rc.3"
features = ["handlebars", "tera"]

[dependencies.rocket_db_pools]
version = "=0.1.0-rc.3"
features = ["sqlx_postgres"]

[default.databases.ecom]
url="postgresql://localhost:5432/default?user=postgres&password=test"
```

and this is my main.rs:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

use rocket::fs::{FileServer, relative};
use rocket::futures::{FutureExt, TryFutureExt};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use rocket_db_pools::{Connection, Database};
use rocket_dyn_templates::{Template, context};
use rocket_db_pools::sqlx::{self, Row};
use sqlx::FromRow;

#[derive(Database)]
#[database("ecom")]
struct Logs(sqlx::PgPool);

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, FromRow)]
#[serde(crate = "rocket::serde")]
pub struct Produit {
    //#[serde(skip_deserializing, skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    id: Option<i64>,
    name: String,
    fk_categorie: String,
}
```

and this is the error code when i build:

```
error: cannot find derive macro `FromRow` in this scope
  --> src\main.rs:14:34
   |
14 | #[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, FromRow)]
   |                                  ^^^^^^^
   |
note: `FromRow` is imported here, but it is only a trait, without a derive macro
  --> src\main.rs:9:5
   |
9  | use sqlx::FromRow;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried to change the version of serde but I got the same error.
How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`sqlx_macros` feature](https://docs.rs/crate/rocket_db_pools/0.1.0-rc.3/features#sqlx_macros) for rocket_db_pools, but unfortunately it doesn't work because the macro requires the sqlx crate is present, so you need to add sqlx to Cargo.toml anyway. You can enable the `macros` feature on sqlx or the `sqlx_macros` feature on rocket_db_pools. Either will do the same thing.

```ini
sqlx = { version = "*", default-features = false, features = ["macros"] }
```